# CSS Animation Assistance

Tags: css

I have a few questions about CSS. I have an animation, listed below.

```
<style> 
div.one
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
position:relative;
animation:skew ease 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
text-align:center;
border-radius:50%;
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
0% {background:red;left:0px;transform:rotat…
25% {background:yellow;left:50px;transform:r…
50% {background:green;left:100px;transform:r…
75% {background:blue;left:50px;transform:rot…
100% {background:red;left:00px;transform:rota…
}

</style>
<div class="one"></div>
```

How could I make it so that one animation could play after the first? For example, animation 'a' would play after 'b' has completed, not while b is occuring.

Comment: It might be worth while to check out `animation-delay`@ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-delay

Answer (score 2):

You can chain 2 or more animations. Here is the code prefixed just with -webkit.

```
-webkit-animation: a 4s linear 0s, b 2s linear 4s;
```

Animation a will play from 0s to 4s, animation b will play from 4s to 6s (4+2).
Here is an example of chaining 2 animations:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtYCW/2/